# Specify `statement_timeout` in Postgresql with sqlalchemy?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

The following statement_timeout option works on some Postgresql databases and on others, I get `Unsupported startup parameter: options`. Why?

Is this possibly a difference between Postgres 9.4 and 9.6? This works with the former servers and fails with the latter.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# As is: Unsupported startup parameter: options
db_engine = create_engine("postgresql://user:pw@host/database",
    connect_args={"options": "-c statement_timeout=1000"})

with db_engine.connect() as db_connection:
    print("got it")
```

Specifically, I get:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) ERROR:  Unsupported startup parameter: options
```

Comment: psycopg2 2.7.1, SQLAlchemy 1.1.11, postgres server 9.6.3. This seems to work another server that is running postgres 9.4.1, but the issue may be something other than the postgres version difference.

Comment: Did you find out what was the issue causing this? I'm banging my head against a wall now :P

Answer (score 2):

You may have been connecting to those databases via PgBouncer.

If so, add `ignore_startup_parameters = options` to pgbouncer.ini under the `[pgbouncer]` section.

From https://www.pgbouncer.org/config.html#ignore_startup_parameters:

> By default, PgBouncer allows only parameters it can keep track of in startup packets: `client_encoding`, `datestyle`, `timezone` and `standard_conforming_strings`. All others parameters will raise an error. To allow others parameters, they can be specified here, so that PgBouncer knows that they are handled by the admin and it can ignore them.
>
> Default: empty

References:

- https://github.com/pgbouncer/pgbouncer/issues/295
- https://github.com/pgbouncer/pgbouncer/issues/496